# open file folder in the directory

Tags: c++, c, file, unix, fork

I want my C++ application to implement "open File Folder" functionality like in that firefox and download manager. This is the code that I've come up with.

```
int File::openTempFile(std::string temp_file_dir)
{
  std::string file_path = temp_file_dir + "/" ;
  file_path = file_path + this->additional_info ;

  // if there is already an temporary file then delete it//
  if( temporary_file != "" )
  {
    // :TODO: open temporary file stack //
    // so when the application dinit we could remove those //
    // remove(temporary_file.c_str() );
  } 

  /* write temporary file */
  FILE* fp = fopen (file_path.c_str(), "w");
  if( fp== NULL)
    return FALSE;
  fwrite( m_data, 1, m_size, fp);
  fclose(fp); 

  // now open it using natulus //
  char * parmList[] = {strdup("nautilus"),strdup(file_path.c_str() )} ;
  int pid;
  if(( pid= fork() ) == -1) 
    perror("fork failed");
  if( pid ==0 ){
    int a = execvp("nautilus" , parmList);
    printf("exevp failed to load the temporary file");
  }
  temporary_file = file_path ;
  return TRUE;
}
```

But Instead of a one nautilus window , it open 3 windows.Any idea what is the reason for that ?And how could I get nautilus "open with" dialog just instead of showing it on the directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a folder, I use the `xdg-open` command which opens the specified folder with the preferred file manager for a given desktop environment.

On my system when I'm running `KDE`, it calls `dolphin` to display the folder, and `xfce4`, it invokes `thunar`, as these are the preferred file managers as per my settings. I often don't want `nautilus` to be used, as the interface differs from my preferred apps, doesn't look consistent with the other applications - in terms of widgets, style, etc. - and won't group the same in my taskbar.

It also uses separate preferences for my default open-with settings, and conflicts with my workflow.

Additionally, `nautilus` isn't necessarily guaranteed to be on my system. 
For example, on some of my older systems, where I've `emerge`d a custom gentoo system where I'm either constrained by RAM or HDD space, I've only `emerge`d say `twm` and `xfce4`, so `nautilus` doesn't exist.

As far as the nautilus-specific behaviour is concerned, I have had similar problems with nautilus creates a desktop on initial invokation (as is the case when I am running `twm`).

Invoking `nautilus --help` shows the following options:

```
Application Options:
  -c, --check                 Perform a quick set of self-check tests.
  --version                   Show the version of the program.
  -g, --geometry=GEOMETRY     Create the initial window with the given geometry.
  -w, --new-window            Always open a new window for browsing specified URIs
  -n, --no-default-window     Only create windows for explicitly specified URIs.
  --no-desktop                Never manage the desktop (ignore the GSettings preference).
  --force-desktop             Always manage the desktop (ignore the GSettings preference).
  -q, --quit                  Quit Nautilus.
  -s, --select                Select specified URI in parent folder.
  --display=DISPLAY           X display to use
```

Unfortunately, I can't help you specifically invoke the `nautilus` "open with..." dialog, although `xdg-open` will use the default application when a file is specified. Perhaps polling configurations within the `mimeapps.list` file (which can be in one of several cascading override locations: including, but not limited to, user-desktop, user, sysadmin-desktop, sysadmin, default-desktop, and default).

Comment: That you sir that's definitely what I wanted.